# Azure blobs on Cloudberry not accepting content-disposition http header

Tags: http-headers, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying to set content-disposition header on blob level and container level per https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1wfbahc4gawhms/Screenshot%202014-04-16%2009.51.24.png but it does not retain the header info. I've tried with setting full access permission to the blob and container and without.

I've checked that we have the latest version 08/15/2013 that according to MS allows for setting content-disposition.

The reason I want to set the content-disposition= attachment ; filename="test.mov" and content-disposition= attachment ; filename=test.mov for the "CT_QTCC608_708.mov" file is that I do NOT want Chrome or other browser to stream the video - I want that video only to be for download once I add the link to the html for a public facing website.

I've tried with both Cerebrata and Cloudberry - Cloudberry tech support says to contact Microsoft as Azure is not accepting the header.

Comment: This works when I try it. Content-Disposition is set as expected. If you are still having problems with this, a fiddler trace (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) of the PUT that is being sent by CloudBerry would help debug.

Comment: Tx. I have fiddler but I'm first time user and don't know how to set up a trace of PUT and proper configuration for Chrome...this is what I have https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hzlk53l78n9tb5/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2014.19.26.png

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that not all tools have been updated to support the `content-disposition` header yet.

It is already supported in Zudio ([link](http://zud.io/)) if you want to give that a try.

Comment: Thanks. I'm able in Zudio to set the content-disposition header but when i click the link to the blob it still streams in Chrome instead of forcing to save as attachment using the name "test.mov" see https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqlqc73qv7d06ww/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2014.09.53.png

Comment: Can you use the Network tab in the Chrome dev tools to see if the response header is getting set?

Comment: Odd. Can you check with Fiddler or Chrome's dev tools to see if the header is actually set when you download (or stream) the blob?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand yet how to work Fiddler. Here's what I see in Chrome dev tools: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ibh82fxe0h1sbn/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2020.26.32.png

Comment: That 304 message is telling your browser that the content hasn't changed since it was last accessed. Try doing a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5) or clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks, i did a hard refresh and get this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilo72gqbi3ec4q5/Screenshot%202014-04-19%2013.48.51.png - the videl still streams in Chrome instead of forcing download.